# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when writing C# List<string> to multiple textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

How to put list to multiple TextBoxes? I have tried to use several way to do it. All of them can put only one value from `List<string>` into TextBox and show an error of `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Below is the code I have tried this far:

```
List<string> txtlist = new List<string>();
 for (int ix = 1; ix < 16; ix++)
{
   string test = command.Get(appendCommand);
   txtlist.Add(test);
   txt_1.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(0);  
   txt_2.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(1); //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
   txt_3.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(2);
   txt_4.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(3);
   ...
   txt_4.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(15);
}
```

List txtlist data show as below:

> [0] "test1" [1] "test2" [2] "test3" .... [15] "test16"

I want to put list one by one to the textbox, please show me some example, thank you.

Comment: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if i have 1 apple and you ask for the second one, what will happen. Now what you need to do is debug your code and work out why... you  add 1 item, then ask for the next 16, it doesn't make sense

Comment: What do you trying to achieve? Is that, you want bind each item in list to each text box or all items in list to all text box?

Comment: @Victor You are creating a `new List<string>()` and in loop you are adding only one item. So it couldn't get other items. To avoid this error you must add text to `textBox` after completing the loop.

Comment: @er-sho yes  i want to binding all the item into different textbox

Comment: @Victor, so whats the critria to bind? means all items are bind with comma separated or any format ?

Comment: @er-sho i have update the question please refresh the page thank you, no comma

Comment: @Victor,  Yes I saw your updated but one more question is, the expected output is same for all textbox or it may vary for different textboxes?

Comment: @er-sho the output would be different and put it in different textbox, different textbox will only  have one output

Comment: @MichaelRandall yes i do too much for it, code too long will don't have a clear mind, i need some coffee. happy coding day

Comment: @Victor, could you please show how different textbox have different output so its clear to understand?

Comment: @er-sho the list have different value it need to put inside different textbox, one textbox only hold one value Risto-M have solve the problem, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First build txtList and after that there are items to get. No more `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

```
List<string> txtlist = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
   string test = command.Get(appendCommand);
   txtlist.Add(test);
}

txt_1.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(0);  
txt_2.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(1); 
txt_3.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(2);
txt_4.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(3);
...
txt_4.Text = txtlist.ElementAt(15);
```

Comment: No problem. Btw, I don't get "List data" part of question description - you have to elaborate your question a bit more on that part.. Or if getting rid of ArgumentOutOfRangeException is enough, you can accept this answer..

Comment: sorry for that i have update the question. too sleepy will make lots of crazy mistake. i will take some rest and back to code again.

Comment: Ok, let's close this then. You can make another question after resting if new problems occur..